# Dart - Way to access a inherited static property from a parent class method

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, static

In PHP there is a way of accessing a static property value that is defined/overridden on an inheritor.

e.g.

```php
class Foo {
   public static $name='Foo';
   public function who(){
     echo static::$name;//the static operator
   }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
   public static $name='Bar';
}
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->who();
//Prints "Bar";
```

Is there ANY way of doing the exact same thing in Dart language?

Comment: Static methods and variables is only part of the class they are defined in. You are not getting them into your subclasses when extending (or implementing) since they are not part of the interface of the class.

Comment: That is such a nice feature from PHP. Opens up huge possibilities for designs. 
I'll have to figure out another way of doing the design I want.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20726598/10157127) might help

Comment: I've read that topic. His need is really fulfilled by the suggestions. Mine is a bit different though.

Comment: If you want a method to be overridable by derived classes, make it a non-`static` method.  It usually doesn't make sense to override `static` methods since overriding necessarily requires an object instance for virtual dispatch to occur.  The meaning of "static" in a `static` method is that it is resolvable at compilation time.  Languages that allow such overriding work only because they allow invoking class methods as instance methods; if that's what you want, just make it an instance method in the first place.

Comment: About making it instance prop/method:
There's a reason for the existence of static properties and methods and it's not having to create a new instance of the object to access a value or functionality that is not mutable. 
Think about a table name for a given model, or table field configuration. None of that information will be different in any instance, reason why they should be consts and because that information belongs to the model but is not attached to instance work it should be static. It's basic understatement of OOP

Comment: About the "meaning of static" and "only work because they allow invoking class methods as instance methods" :
That affirmation is actually wrong. 
In the case of PHP, as per the example above, the Language is providing a way to access the TYPE of the class calling the method in the inheritance chain.
A(methodA) >B > C. When C calls methodA, PHP allows you to know that the class type you're in is indeed C, but there's no object instance attached to it. the word "static" there is a replacement for the caller class type itself

Answer (score 0):

Addressing comments:

> About making it instance prop/method: There's a reason for the existence of static properties and methods and it's not having to create a new instance of the object to access a value or functionality that is not mutable.

Yes, but that's not how *you* are using it.  *Your* use case is to invoke the method on an object, and therefore you really want an instance method.  Now, some languages automatically allow invoking class methods as instance methods, and I see two choices for a language that offers that ability:

- Statically transform `fooInstance.classMethod()` to `ClassFoo.classMethod()` based on the *declared* type (not the runtime type) of the object.  This is what Java and C++ do.
- Implicitly generate virtual instance methods that call the class method.  This would allow `fooInstance.classMethod()` to invoke the appropriate method based on the runtime type of the object.  For example, given:

  ```dart
  class Foo {
    static void f() => print('Foo.f');
  }
  ```

  You instead could write:

  ```dart
  class Foo {
    static void classMethod() => print('Foo.f');
    final instanceMethod = classMethod;
  }
  ```

  and then you either could call `Foo.classMethod()` or `Foo().instanceMethod()` and do the same thing.

In either case, it's syntactic sugar and therefore isn't anything that you couldn't do yourself by being more verbose.

> About the "meaning of static" and "only work because they allow invoking class methods as instance methods" : That affirmation is actually wrong. In the case of PHP, as per the example above, the Language is providing a way to access the TYPE of the class calling the method in the inheritance chain. A(methodA) >B > C. When C calls methodA, PHP allows you to know that the class type you're in is indeed C, but there's no object instance attached to it. the word "static" there is a replacement for the caller class type itself

All of that is still known at compilation time.  That `C` derives from `B` derives from `A` is statically known, so when you try to invoke `C.methodA`, the compiler knows that it needs to look for `methodA` in `B` and then in `A`.  There's no dynamic dispatch that occurs at runtime; that is still compile-time syntactic sugar.  That is, if you wanted, you could explicitly write:

```dart
class A {
  static void methodA() {}
}

class B extends A {
  static void methodA() => A.methodA();
}

class C extends B {
  static void methodA() => B.methodA();
}
```

---

Anyway, in your example, you could write:

```dart
class Foo {
   static String name = 'Foo';
   String get nameFromInstance => name;
   
   void who() {
     print(nameFromInstance);
   }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
   static String name = 'Bar';
  
   @override
   String get nameFromInstance => name;
}

void main() {
  var bar = Bar();
  bar.who(); // Prints: Bar
}
```

Comment: I see the point, for sure. But all that I was already aware of.
Thing is, I'm probably gonna have to place at the original question all that I intent to do, to display the actual problems and the actual design, so we can figure out.
In reality I'm trying to create a Model class like Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord. 
One of the best model-database designs ever. But it seems flutter doesn't want it to run. Even using json serializable I would have to fork it to make it actually create more meaningful methods.

Comment: Do you thing It's worth it to explain how Ruby ActiveRecord works so we can figure out something? I have been working with flutter since 1.x and it's 100% better now, specially after 2.8. But such things, as a model class for a Firestore database, that can be easily configured and prepared so when you do things like someProductInstance.save() everything happens on the background of that call, including asserts, and all, but all functionality inherited from a parent Model/ActiveRecord.

Comment: One thing I can say is that, If json_serializable had an instance method to FILL the object from a JSON, not a factory, I could work with that and move forward without the need for static stuff. But How can I call a inherited class Factory constructor dynamically? Well, cant. Maybe I'll just fork json_serializable and do that.
Or you and other google engineers can help me out put this ActiveRecord class out

Comment: I'm 100% confident that this class design following most of the ActiveRecord stuff from ruby, would be game changer for Firestore and Flutter marriage.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira A clear example of what you are trying to accomplish would help a lot.  As it currently stands, it seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you think you could solve it with inherited static properties (which again, would just be syntactic sugar and therefore wouldn't let you do anything you can't already do).

Comment: I'll setup an example at the question.

Comment: Also, in this example I'll try to keep everything under instance method. But one thing for sure is that I'll be referencing json_serializable in order to have json to class instance conversions.